# does amazon route 53 load balancing using normal dns round robin or some magic?

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-route53

so I am looking for load balancing service for simple php cluster servers that hosted outside of aws

I know the concept about dns load balancing and its pros and cons.

looking at route53 and its health check service and auto Failover feature I cant understand if all its really doing is just auto manage the dns record for me so when a node is down its just getting out of the dns records and getting back when its up or its uses some magic?

if its the first cast(normal dns records) then if some client cache the dns records of my website than even on failure he could still be directed into my failed nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article of [Choosing a Routing Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html) gives you the best overview. The failover is DNS based, but the load balancing is not necessarily based on a simple *round robin* that would give all possible `A` records to anyone; it can be configured to give different servers based on region etc. as well as it can be configured to monitor for unhealthy servers and drop them from responses.

As every DNS based solution, there's always *time to live* `TTL` involved: it will take `TTL` seconds for every change to take effect for alreay cached queries. According to the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/) you must keep this in mind as you need to decide the most suitable `TTL` by yourself.

> Amazon Route 53 does not have a default TTL for any record type. You
>   must always specify a TTL for each record so that caching DNS
>   resolvers can cache your DNS records to the length of time specified
>   through the TTL.

Comment: thanks so just to make sure its dns based solution in case someone cache the dns result for 24 hour they will be directed to my failed server?

Comment: That's exactly why you set the `TTL` for something shorter, e.g. `300` for 5 minutes.